# Is there a limitation of array sizes in ElasticSearch?

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, indexing, document

So I try to add an object with an array of 5m elements (strings). It looks like short strings `["123", "bela",...]`. ES 5.5 indexes it all **as if** it is all `Ok`, yet it kills the index with all data in it (`_count` returns 0 elements). Is there some index setting that shall be changed to allow for long arrays, or just put it all into a string is a must?

Comment: What do you mean by "it kills the index with all data in it"? Can you be more descriptive.

Comment: Say you had 30k hits on `*` query, after indexing an item with a large array in it you get 0